# Housekeeping App — does it make sense?

Tags: meaning, connotation, proper-nouns, translation

We are providing an app which manages your finances — like a housekeeping book. Our space is limited; therefore, we want to use the slogan "Housekeeping App".
Would an English speaker know what is meant by that?

Comment: I would be wondering how an App would sweep, wipe counters, etc.

Comment: I agree with Ben.  "Housekeeping" to me implies sweeping, washing dishes, doing laundry.  "Housekeeping book" is not familiar to me either.  If you mean household finances, a checkbook register or a ledger book might be more suitable starting points.

Comment: Hm, housekeeping is a term frequently used in computing, but not generally targeted towards the user - more of a means to label your internal maintenance mechanisms. I can't think of a developer that would think literally of household tasks when this crops up... actually, scratch that, I can.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: that's at least 2, three if you're included. :-)

Comment: `Book-keeping` is the term I would use.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on my comment, housekeeping to me has the wrong connotation. Perhaps the word you're looking for is bookkeeping? (Although that arguably has some negative connotations with regards to gambling, I reckon.)

Edit to add: Another "word" that might work for you is HouseBook. I've never heard the term before, but it might allow you to allude to the specific nature of this App, while also including a nod to bookkeeping. As [Steve mentions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25589/housekeeping-app-does-it-make-sense/25593#25593), in the product description you should refer to personal finance.

Comment: Thank you, Is housekeeping book at least correct?

Comment: I have not heard that term used either, but it might be an American/British (or some other nationality) thing. I live in the US.

Comment: @Phil: No; as others have commented, housekeeping doesn't relate to finance.

Comment: +1, `book-keeping` is what I would use.

Comment: +1, I go for book-keeping. Personally I think that the financial connotations of "housekeeping" are there but quite dated: it sounds like a Dickensian kind of thing (in *Bleak House* Esther Summerson acts as John Jarndyce's housekeeper, but she's not the one doing the all sweeping: she essentially has a managerial role, including keeping the books).

Answer (score 5):

If you mean that, just by the slogan "housekeeping app", an English speaker would be likely to think you are talking about an app that manages finances, then the answer is definitely no.

The primary meaning of *housekeeping* is cleaning and repairing the house.  Keeping track of personal finances is not generally considered part of *housekeeping* at all.

If anything, I would consider the management of finances to be "finance tracking".

Answer (score 3):

A general term for software which allows you to manage your own finances would be *personal finance software*.

There are examples of references to such software on other Stack Exchange sites, for example:

- "[What are the best software tools for personal finance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/what-are-the-best-software-tools-for-personal-finance)" (Money.SE)
- "[Software for personal finance](https://superuser.com/questions/4927/software-for-personal-finance)" (SuperUser)
- "[Are there personal finance applications offering both an iPhone and a mac version?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/are-there-personal-finance-applications-offering-both-an-iphone-and-a-mac-version)" (Apple.SE)

As several others have mentioned, "housekeeping" is not the right word here, as it doesn't convey any association with money.

However, an app called *Accountant* might convey the right idea.